# How can I change the value of an instance variable

Tags: java

I am doing the code academy project, Build a droid. 
I can do the steps 12 and part of 13 but the third part of the past asks to create another instance ( Droid dan = new Droid("Dan"); ) and to create a energyTransfer method that exchanges batteryLevel between them. See what i have attempted below, I do not know if I am even on the correct path. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you! :)

```
this.batteryLevel = newBatteryLevel;
newBatteryLevel = batteryLevel;"

'public class Droid{

String name;
int batteryLevel;

public Droid(String droidName){
name = droidName;
batteryLevel = 100;

}

public String toString(){
return "Hello I am droid " + name;
}

 public void performTask(String task){
System.out.println(name + " is performing task: " + task);
batteryLevel = batteryLevel - 10;

 }

 public void energyReport(){
 System.out.println(name + "'s Battery level is:" + batteryLevel);
}


public void energyTransfer(int newBatteryLevel) {
   if (codey.batteryLevel > 10 ){
  codey.batteryLevel = batteryLevel - 5;
}
else if (codey.batteryLevel < 10 && codey.batteryLevel > 1 ){
  System.out.println("Transfer of energy not allowed at current power 
level");
}
else {
  System.out.println("Droid battery is depleted");
}


}


public static void main(String[] args){
Droid codey = new Droid("Codey");
Droid dan = new Droid("Dan");
System.out.println(codey);
codey.performTask("Walking");
codey.energyReport();
codey.performTask("Coding");
codey.energyReport();
codey.performTask("Cleaning");
codey.energyReport();
codey.performTask("Buying a house");
codey.energyReport();
dan.energyReport();

  }

 }'
```

I have 2 instances codey and dan. If Codey has 60% battery remaining. I expected to be able to minus 20% from dan battery remaining and add it to codey battery remaining (energyTransfer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it well. But energyTransfer method could be like:

```
public void energyTransfer(Droid aux){
    if(this.batteryLevel == 60 && aux.batteryLevel >= 20){
       this.batteryLevel += 20;
       aux.batteryLevel -= 20;
    }
 }
```

And your main:

```
Droid codey = new Droid("Codey");
Droid dan = new Droid("Dan");
/* ... */
codey.energyTransfer(dan);
```

Comment: what if battery percentages will be dynamic

Comment: I didn't undestand if codey's battery has to be 60 or less equal 60

Comment: The values in the if statement i have choosen to try ensure that batteryLevel is above 0 and can transfer energy without going below 0. I am a beginner at coding so this is my first attempt at writing something on my own.

Comment: In the line  " public void energyTransfer(Droid aux){ " what is the aux term "doing"? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: aux replaces the object transfered in: codey.energyTransfer(dan); So aux == dan.

Comment: Wow, this worted a treat! thank you for help me out. What is the term "this" doing in the line "if(this.batteryLevel == 60 && aux.batteryLevel >= 20){" i can understand that its identifying the battery level but what would its actaul definition be? I updated my code referencing yours with >   public void energyTransfer(Droid aux){
    if(this.batteryLevel > 10 && aux.batteryLevel >= 20){
       this.batteryLevel += 10;
       aux.batteryLevel -= 10;
    }
 } to transfer "10%". It worked! thank you :)

Comment: When you execute codey.energyTransfer(dan); this == codey.

Answer (score 0):

If I would have been in your place, I would have created a separated energy Transfer Class which will take the responsibility of exchanging energies between the two instances as it is not the responsibility of Your Droid Class **(As per SRP)**

So it is better to take out the energy transfer code from your Droid class and put it in a new class like below

```
class EnergyTransfer {


    public void energyTransfer(Droid from, Droid to) {
         //Add your code transfer logic here

    }
}
```

Create a separate main class which will have the main method, something like below

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Droid codey = new Droid("Codey");
        Droid dan = new Droid("Dan");
        System.out.println(codey);
        codey.performTask("Walking");
        codey.energyReport();
        codey.performTask("Coding");
        codey.energyReport();
        codey.performTask("Cleaning");
        codey.energyReport();
        codey.performTask("Buying a house");
        codey.energyReport();
        dan.energyReport();

        EnergyTransfer transfer = new EnergyTransfer();
        transfer.energyTransfer(codey, dan);
    }
}
```

Comment: i haven't got as far as having 2 classes...

EnergyTransfer transfer = new EnergyTransfer();
        transfer.energyTransfer(codey, dan);

is this statement calling and taking information from the second class?

Comment: These are two new classes which you could have. One is the EnergyTransfer class having a method energyTransfer. This method can be called from outside like whenever your application feels the need to transfer energy. In your case, you can call it from the main method as 
transfer.energyTransfer(codey, dan)
which indicates you want to transfer energy from codey to dan.

Your current Droid class may perform the existing task and let the other class do the energy transfer.

Comment: But if you want to do the transfer in your POJO class only then you can follow the approach as suggested by @Graiton.
But this violates SRP. Your POJO class should not be performing any businesslogic rather it's service class should do the same.

Comment: HI Sharique, I appreciate this may not be the correct way to structure a program, but at the minute i am just trying to figure out methods, instances and calling information between them! I may try this a go when my understanding of the basics increases! thank you for the reply!